# Applying OGNL expression to a context variable

Tags: variables, struts2, expression, ognl

I'm currently working with Struts2 (inexperienced developer) and I've been searching but I couldn't find how to apply an OGNL expression to a variable stored in context.

The thing is that I need to retrieve a parameter from Context and uppercase it. By now, I've tried to do it this way but sadly with no luck:

```
<s:property value="#myVar.toUpperCase()" />
```

As this works with variables stored in the ValueStack (notation without #), I don't really understand why this won't work with anything stored in Context..

I'm able to print the `#myVar`content just fine if I don't append the `.toUpperCase()` to it.

Also tried this workaround but didn't help:

```
<s:property value="<s:property value="#myVar"/>.toUpperCase()"/>
```

So what's the thing I'm missing? How can I apply an OGNL expression to a variable stored in Context?

Comment: What do you mean by variable in context? How did you put it there?

Comment: I've put it in there by sending it through hidden parameter:

In another JSP:
`<s:hidden name="myVar"/>`

Then inside the JSP I'm trying to uppercase it I did the following instead of trying to access it from `#parameters.myVar` :
`<s:set var="myVar" value="%{#parameters.myVar}"/>`

Comment: Any reason to get value via `#parameters`? Why don't you map it into action property and get it from the action?

Comment: Im setting it through #parameters because I thought it would be cleaner and easier than declaring a new String inside the action .java as I need it just for read-only. Anyways, as I said, I'm new to developing so any advice/guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know your requirements but it is nothing wrong with adding property inside action.

Comment: @AleksandrM Ok, I'll keep that in mind, just thought the action would be more easy to read with few properties inside :). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable most probably isn't a String so there isn't `toUpperCase()` method in it. The solution is to call `toString()` before calling `toUpperCase()`.

```
<s:property value="#myVar.toString().toUpperCase()" />
```

**Update**

Actually your problem is here `<s:set var="myVar" value="%{#parameters.myVar}"/>` since there could be more then one `myVar` in parameters it will return an array of Strings, so if you want just a single parameter change your expression to `#parameters.myVar[0]` and then `toUpperCase()` will work.

```
<s:set var="myVar" value="%{#parameters.myVar[0]}"/>
<s:property value="#myVar.toUpperCase()" />
```

OR

```
<s:set var="myVars" value="%{#parameters.myVar}"/>
<s:property value="#myVars[0].toUpperCase()" />
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it prints the following:
`[LJAVA.LANG.STRING;@11ADBF9D`

This `#myVar` comes from the `#parameters` context scope, and I'm passing it as a hidden parameter from another JSP, where I can confirm it's a String (`myVar` has an username inside of it)

Comment: @Jorge33212: Try `<s:property value="#myVar" />` and `<s:property value="#myVar.getClass()" />` and post what it prints.

Comment: @Jorge33212 You are trying to upperCase a List<String>... :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Array actually.

Comment: `<s:property value="#myVar" />` prints "Roberto Alvarez"
`<s:property value="#myVar.getClass()"`prints "class [Ljava.lang.String;"  
Seems I'm trying to uppercase an Array as you point.. D:. Maybe because when I pass the hidden parameter I passed it like this:
<s:hidden name="myVar"  value="%{name+' '+surname}"/>

Comment: Worked like a charm @AleksandrM, thank you all so much for your time and patience :)